# Magento 1.9 in responsive emulator?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

I've checked in a number of magento 1.9 demo sites, as well as my own but can't work out what's stopping it being shown in all the responsive emulators - screenfly etc... Anyone shed some light on this for me?

Example http://clients-sherodesigns.com/newstore/ in http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: Please could you elaborate on "stopping it being shown"?

Comment: They all return a blank page, no header, footer or content.

Comment: Hmm, see what you mean.

Comment: same thing happens with me too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the X-frame policy, Magento has a built-in feature that denies calls from an iframe.

Screenfly uses such an Iframe to display the content.
To solve this , you can enable the proxy in screenfly (the eye-button) or change to following setting in your Magento.

Go to your adminpanel

- System
- Configuration
- Admin
- Security

And set the "Allow Magento Frontend to run in frame" to Enabled.
[image: Allow Magento Frontend]