# I want to insert a iframe to my domain page, when I iframe a magento home-page, I get blank page

Tags: cms, iframe

I want to insert a iframe to my domain page, when I  iframe a magento home-page, i get blank page.
for example: my domain is www.a.com, I put this code on my page:

```
<iframe frameborder="no" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute;" src="http://www.b.com"></iframe>
```

[image]

I want iframe the domain "b.com" content.  but I get a blank page.

additional: a.com is bulid in zencart,  b.com is build in magento.
I guess it is the cms Loading problem, but I do not know how to solve. Can you help me?

I asked somebody they only said that, the magento cms page can only load once，so when iframe a magento page I get a blank page.. I need to writte the magento cms-page code to the temple. Is it right?

Comment: Let me clarify; you are trying to embed a magento store into a Zencart page via an iFrame, is that correct? If so, I believe this to be a Zencart issue, rather than a Magento one; please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I donot thinck this to be a Zencart issue, zencart can iframe all other page, but ONLY the magento domain page

Comment: This is CORS problem. You can use a proxy to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to had an Iframe in the HEAD of the page.

Iframes are part of the BODY

Try this

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<iframe>...</iframe>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I think its possible to integrate any site on other site by frames...BUT its a DIRTY WAY...

Comment: thanks to reply to me,but it does't work.

Comment: Could you please post your new code ?

Comment: the code do not work, I need to writte the magento cms-page code to the temple. but I do not know how.

Comment: In your html_header.php file, do you see a <body>, just after put your <iframe> code

Comment: I just discover a new thing in the last version of magento : see the response on that thread...it could help you... http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26267/magento-1-9-in-responsive-emulator?rq=1

Comment: That's the problem!